# knife ssh to odd numbered hosts

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Is there a way I can ssh to odd numbered hosts?

this works:

```
# knife ssh "webhost1*" "chef-client"
```

this does not work

```
# knife ssh "webhost1[13579]" "chef-client"
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this natively, you'll need to look at other properties of node that can be [searched](https://docs.chef.io/workstation/knife_ssh/). Like roles, tags, etc. One way is to [tag the nodes](https://docs.chef.io/workstation/knife_tag/). For example, we can tag the nodes as `odd` and `even`, i.e. `webhost1[13579]` will be tagged as odd.

Then the odd hosts can be targeted by:

```
knife ssh "name:webhost1* AND tags:odd" "chef-client"
```

Generating odd numbers for the `knife ssh` command to use is more of a Shell functionality, e.g.:

```
for num in $(seq 1 2 10); do knife ssh "webhost1$num" "chef-client"; done
```

The `seq` command will generate a sequence starting from `1` with increments of `2`, till `10`.
Note that this makes the SSH execution serial, and there may be better or more efficient ways to generate the odd numbers. Also, you can use a similar `for` loop to tag the nodes if required. Example:

```
for num in $(seq 1 2 10); do knife tag create "webhost1$num" odd; done
```